# Delete a row from Datagrid view and also from object in windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form with a datagridview which gets populated from an object in another class (basically this object acts like a database throughout the application). The selected row gets deleted when user clicks a button. The row should be deleted from dgv and also from that object.

There is also a search criteria which will reduce the number of rows displayed in dgv. Now when user opts for this search and selects a row from reduced number of rows, I am not able to handle the delete row logic.

Currently I am having the row number in INT variable and deleting the same instance in object list. I know this wont work when rows are reduced. Thanks in advance for your help.

In form :

```
private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
class obj=new class();
int row = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
obj.deleteName(row);
dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(row);
}
```

In class:

```
class Class
{
List<string> names=new list<string>();

public void deleteName(int index)
{
names.RemoveAt(index);
}

}
```

Comment: Actually they are populated with a list of another class objects. Two classes A and B where B has list of A. And in form I populate with list of objects of B(which is collection of A).

Answer (score 3):

Here are some suggestions, using as much of your current code as possible.

Create a custom class to populate the `DataGridView`:

```
public class MyData
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Then you can access the current item from the grid using:

```
var currentRow = (MyData)dataGridView1.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem;

obj.DeleteRecord(currentRow);
```

And use that record when deleting from the collection:

```
class Class
{
    List<MyData> records = new List<MyData>();

    public void DeleteRecord(MyData record)
    {
        records.Remove(record);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So, if I'm understanding correctly you're deleting it visually, but not in the source list?  The way I'd do it so to have it as an `System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<T>` and perform all the adding/removing operations on that.  Your view will synch with the list because ObservableCollection reports changes.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of deleting objects based on `Index`, you may use the `string` itself to search for in the binded list in your class `Class` like below:

```
class Class
{
    List<string> names=new list<string>();

    public void deleteName(string name)
    {
        names.Remove(names.Single(x => x == name));
    }
}
```

Then you can just rebind the DataGridView with the updated `names` list.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried this. What will happen when there are 2 strings with same name ?

Comment: Then I would suggest you to maintain another hidden column of `Id` like types which should uniquely point to each row. So at `btnDelete_Click`, pick up the value of that `Id` column for the `current` row and delete the same in class `Class`. But then you should also maintain another field of `Id` in that List mapping to each string.

Comment: Is it possible to maintain some index in DGV without affecting the class. Like for example, there are 7 rows and index in dgv is from 0 to 6. During search rows 1 and 5 are selected. Still in dgv, the index of rows should be 1 and 5 and not 1,2. Is it possible ? Thanks a lot for your reply

Comment: AFAIK, WinForms DGV doesn't support this feature. So, unfortunately you have to adopt the possible way.

Comment: I did as you suggested. It doesnt work. This is what I did:
`code`
    for (int i = 0; i < classA.Count; i++)
    {
    if (Convert.ToInt32(classA[i].RowNumber) == Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1[0, row].Value))
    {
    classB obj = new classB(classA[i].RowNumber,classA[i].Name);
    classA.deleteNote(obj);
    break;
    }
    }

In class:
    public void deleteNote(classB obj)
    {
    classA obj1
    obj1.Remove(obj);
    }

Comment: would you please clear me on some point on your recent code? you have invoked `classA.deleteNote(obj);`, which implies that `ClassA` has a method named `deleteNote` that takes a `ClassB` instance as an argument. But you have declared another instance of `ClassA` (`obj1`) inside the method and invoked `Remove` on `obj1`. You even didn't initialize `obj1`. In this case, you don't need to declare another instance of `ClassA` (`obj1` in this case) inside a method which itself resides inside of `ClassA`. So please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Small Change, sorry for the confusion.

`code`
    for (int i = 0; i < classA.Count; i++)
    {
    if (Convert.ToInt32(classA[i].RowNumber) == Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1[0, row].Value))
    {
    classB obj = new classB(classA[i].RowNumber,classA[i].Name);
    classA.deleteNote(obj);
    break;
    }
    }

In class:
    public void deleteNote(classB obj)
    {
    list<classA> obj1=new list<classA>();
    obj1.Remove(obj);
    }

The list object I mentioned is declared globally and has the list of classA objects

Comment: I got it now. Thanks a lot for trying.

Comment: I did the same thing as you said. I changed the delete function like this :
public void deleteNote(noteClass objNote)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < notes.Count; i++)
            {
                if (objNote.RowNumber == notes[i].RowNumber)
                {
                    notes.RemoveAt(i);
                }
            }
        }

Thanks a lot !!!

Comment: it would be nice also for others if the appropriate answer is `accepted`. Thanks!